# Citation in figure caption showing up as text in list of tables

Tags: latex

When using `\cite` in a caption for a figure, the citation shows up as the citation number in the caption (as it should) but as text in the list of figures. I never ran into this problem before so I'm not sure what's going on.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx,changepage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@table}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.5em}}
\makeatother

\listoftables

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics [width=0.7\textwidth] {Images/cnc-processing-center-centateq-p-110_01.jpg}
    \caption{Homag Centateq P-110 \cite{HOMAG}}
    \label{fig:cnc_mill}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Figure]

[image: List of figures]

Answer (score 0):

i tried compiling your code on overleaf, to do that, i added some lines on your code as is show following:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx,changepage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@table}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.5em}}
\makeatother

\listoftables
\listoffigures %added to provide a list of figures

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics [width=0.7\textwidth] {test.pdf}
    \caption{Homag Centateq P-110 \cite{HOMAG}}
    \label{fig:cnc_mill}
\end{figure}

\begin{thebibliography}{9} % Added the thebibliography enviromment to use Homag as exemple.

\bibitem{HOMAG} 
Homag. 

\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

[image]

As is shown on the figure above, the list of figures is like you want. I suspect that you have troubles with your LaTex compiler, try do a upgrade on your compiler or use another, like overleaf.